# fetchRecordCompletionBlock and semaphores - help understanding execution order

Tags: swift, cloudkit

Context:

- App with all data in CloudKit
- ViewController calls a query to load the data for a tableview
- tableview crashes because the array of data for the tableview hasn't
  come back from CK
- I've researched semaphores and have it *nearly*
  working But can't seem to figure out where to place the
  semaphore.signal() to get the exact right behaviour

within viewDidLoad, I call the function:

```
 Week.fetchWeeks(for: challenge!.weeks!) { weeks in
        self.weeks = weeks
    }
```

and the function:

```
static func fetchWeeks(for references: [CKRecord.Reference],
                       _ completion: @escaping ([Week]) -> Void) {
    let recordIDs = references.map { $0.recordID }
    let operation = CKFetchRecordsOperation(recordIDs: recordIDs)
    operation.qualityOfService = .utility
    let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)

    operation.fetchRecordsCompletionBlock = { records, error in
        let weeks = records?.values.map(Week.init) ?? []

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            completion(weeks)
            //Option 1: putting semaphore.signal() here means it never completes
            // beyond initialization of the week records 
        }
        //Option 2: putting semaphore.signal() here means it completes after the
        // initialization of the Week items, but before completion(weeks) is done 
        // so the array isn't initialized in the view controller in time.  so the
        // VC tries to use weeks and unwraps a nil.
        semaphore.signal()
    }

    Model.currentModel.publicDB.add(operation)
    semaphore.wait() // blocking the thread until .signal is called        
}
```

Note: I have tested that the weeks array within the view controller is properly set eventually - so it does seem to be purely a timing issue :)

I've tested placement of .signal() and if I put it within the 'DispatchQueue.main.async' block, it never gets triggered - probably because that block itself is waiting for the signal.

However if I put it anywhere else, then the viewcontroller picks up at that point and the completion(weeks) doesn't get called in time.

Maybe it is obvious - but as my first time working with semaphores - I'm struggling to figure it out!

> Update 1: It works with DispatchQueue(label: "background")

I was able to get it working once I twigged that the semaphore.wait() was never going to get called with semaphore.signal() on the main thread.

So I changed it from:
DispatchQueue.main.async 
to
DispatchQueue(label: "background").async and popped the semaphore.signal() inside and it did the trick

Comments/critiques welcome!

```
    static func fetchWeeks(for references: [CKRecord.Reference],
                           _ completion: @escaping ([Week]) -> Void) {
        NSLog("inside fetchWeeks in Week ")
        let recordIDs = references.map { $0.recordID }
        let operation = CKFetchRecordsOperation(recordIDs: recordIDs)

        operation.qualityOfService = .utility
        let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)

        operation.fetchRecordsCompletionBlock = { records, error in

            if error != nil {
                print(error?.localizedDescription)
            }

            let weeks = records?.values.map(Week.init) ?? []

            DispatchQueue(label: "background").async {
                completion(weeks)
                semaphore.signal()
            }

        }
        Model.currentModel.publicDB.add(operation)
        semaphore.wait() // blocking the thread until .signal is called
    }

}
```

> Update 2: Trying to avoid use of semaphores

Per comment thread - we shouldn't need to use semaphores with CloudKit - so it is likely that I'm doing something stupid :)

moving fetchWeeks() to the viewController to try to isolate the issue...but it still blows up as fetchWeeks() has't completed before the code tries to execute the line after and use the weeks array

my viewController:

```
class ChallengeDetailViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var rideTableView: UITableView!
//set by the inbound segue
var challenge: Challenge?
// set in fetchWeeks based on the challenge
var weeks: [Week]?

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    rideTableView.dataSource = self
    rideTableView.register(UINib(nibName: K.cellNibName, bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: K.cellIdentifier)
    rideTableView.delegate = self

    fetchWeeks(for: challenge!.weeks!) { weeks in
        self.weeks = weeks
    }
//This is where it blows up as weeks is nil
    weeks = weeks!.sorted(by: { $0.weekSequence < $1.weekSequence })   
 }

//moved this to the view controller
func fetchWeeks(for references: [CKRecord.Reference],
                       _ completion: @escaping ([Week]) -> Void) {

    let recordIDs = references.map { $0.recordID }
    let operation = CKFetchRecordsOperation(recordIDs: recordIDs)
    operation.qualityOfService = .utility

    operation.fetchRecordsCompletionBlock = { records, error in

        if error != nil {
            print(error?.localizedDescription)
        }

        let weeks = records?.values.map(Week.init) ?? []

        DispatchQueue.main.sync {
            completion(weeks)
        }
    }
    Model.currentModel.publicDB.add(operation)
}
```

Comment: **Never** use semaphores with the CloudKit API. It's not needed at all. Where does the crash occur? And it's highly recommended to handle the potential `error` in  `fetchRecordsCompletionBlock`

Comment: @vadian - the crash occurs back in the main view controller when it attempts to use the array that hasn't yet come back from DispatchQueue.main.async.  Good spot on the error, will address.

Comment: @vadian - I figured it out by using DispatchQueue(label: "background").async - though given your emphasis on *Never* using semaphores with CloudKit - I'm intrigued to understand if I should have tackled it differently and it is just luck that this works?  Also added in the error handling :) - I'm a complete beginner - so any insights you can share would be very helpful!

Comment: The semaphore is completely pointless because the completion handler is asynchronous anyway.  It's horrible practice. Delete it!

Comment: deleting it causes the app to crash....and it works with it.  without it, the app goes on to try to use the array that is returned *Before* it exists.  If there is more information I can provide about the flow of my app - let me know!

Comment: You have to access the array which is passed in the completion closure `[Week]) -> Void`.  The asynchronous behavior of `CKFetchRecordsOperation` is reliable and straightforward. Please read the documentation of CloudKit and the provided sample code. You will find no semaphore at all.

Comment: I've tried (via Update 2 section in the question) to move fetchWeeks across - but still crashes without the semaphores :(  - will keep trying, given I get that I *shouldn't* use them, but let me know if anything jumps out at you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once again: **Never use semaphores with the CloudKit API**.

First of all declare data source arrays always as non-optional empty arrays to get rid of unnecessary unwrapping the optional

```
var weeks = [Week]()
```

The mistake is that you don't use the fetched data at the right place.

As the closure is asynchronous you have to proceed **inside** the closure

```
fetchWeeks(for: challenge!.weeks!) { [weak self] weeks in
    self?.weeks = weeks
    self?.weeks = weeks.sorted(by: { $0.weekSequence < $1.weekSequence }) 
}
```

or simpler

```
fetchWeeks(for: challenge!.weeks!) { [weak self] weeks in
    self?.weeks = weeks.sorted{ $0.weekSequence < $1.weekSequence }
}
```

And if you need to reload the table view do it also **inside** the closure

```
fetchWeeks(for: challenge!.weeks!) { [weak self] weeks in
    self?.weeks = weeks.sorted{ $0.weekSequence < $1.weekSequence }
    self?.rideTableView.reloadData()
}
```

To do so you have to call `completion` on the main thread

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    completion(weeks)
}
```

And finally delete the ugly semaphore!

```
let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
...
semaphore.signal()
...
semaphore.wait()
```

Comment: oooh - very helpful, thank you.  will give it a shot tonight!

Comment: thanks so much for your patience in getting me to the right solution instead of a hack job!  That did the trick - no sempahores with the cloudkit API and code that works beautifully :)